# Disable Experience Editor for a single page

Tags: experience-editor

I know you can disable experience editor for accounts and users through Security Editor (by hiding the buttons, etc), but is there a way to disable the Experience Editor on a page-by-page basis.

For example, let's say I have page A and page B. Page A functions like any normal page and content authors can load it in experience editor. When they navigate to page B, the experience editor ribbon follows them and load the page with the Experience Editor ribbon. But is there a way to make Page B not experience editor enabled - making the experience editor not load when users navigate to Page B - but keep it enabled for other pages?

Comment: Should the authors be able to edit that page at all? What about in the content editor? Maybe if you give the reasoning for this a solution can be found.

Comment: Sure. We don't want content editors to be able to modify just this page through Experience Editor, but they should (and do) have access to edit the page through content editor. The content editor has some fields that the content editors should be able to modify (for example, controls for enabling a social sharing widget).

But we don't want them to load the page in exp editor and accidentally move presentation details around.

Answer (score 1):

As you are really just concerned with the editor's ability to be able to move / change components, I would suggest that you just use the ability of Placeholder Settings to restrict what users can design components on a page, rather than try to block access to that page in the Experience Editor altogether.

This is done by removing the `Read` permission for the content editors on the Placeholder Settings item used by that page. This will prevent the editors from being able to change the components, though they will still be able to edit any editable fields, if there are any.

If your Placeholder Settings are part of standard values, or just referenced by multiple pages, you will want to make sure you only affect the one page. For this, you can duplicate the settings item to create a "Restricted" version that just differs by having that permission restriction applied to it. You can then edit the page in question to override the layout and change it to use that Placeholder Settings instead of the regular one.